# ( iOS ) What is superview and what is subviews

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, view, objective-c++

What is superview and what is subviews?

When I add this code:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.frontView];
// what does that mean ?
```

And...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *frontView;
[self.frontView superview] != nil // means ?
```

what is in superview?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A **superview** is a view that holds other views over it and **subviews** are the views being held/added over a **View**.

Let's assume we have a view named **MyView**, which holds a **UIButton** (named **loginButton**) over it. Here **MyView** is considered a **superview** for **loginButton** and **loginButton** is considered a **subview** of **MyView**.

[For more, you should start from here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW24)

As per the provided code snippet.

```
[self.view addSubview:self.frontView];
```

Hence **view** (Controller's view) is a **superview** and **frontView** is a **subview**

Answer (score 5):

"superview" means the view which holds the current one.
"subviews" means the views which are holding by the curent view.

For example, you have a view (will call it as MyView) which include a button.
Button is a view too (UIButton is a kind of view).
So, MyView is superview for the button.
Button is a subview for MyView.

Answer (score 1):

See Apple's [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH1-SW2), section [View Hierarchies and Subview Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW24)

Answer (score 1):

subview is childview ( which is added on any view)

superview is parentview (on which subview is added)