# What's the difference between view and superview?

Tags: ios

What´s the difference between `view` and `superview`?

```
let fromViewController = self.source

let containerView = fromViewController.view.superview
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123306/ios-what-is-superview-and-what-is-subviews

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the two properties? What part needs further explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Views** are the fundamental building blocks of your app's user interface, and the UIView class defines the behaviors that are common to all views. A view object renders content within its bounds rectangle and handles any interactions with that content.

`let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100)
let myView = UIView(frame: rect)`

The **superview** is the immediate ancestor of the current view. The value of this property is nil when the view is not installed in a view hierarchy. To set the value of this property, use the addSubview(_:) method to embed the current view inside another view.

`let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100)
 let myView = self.view.addSubview( UIView(frame: rect))`

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that

```
let v1 = UIView()
parent.addSubview(v1)
```

here

> v1 ----- >>> v1 ( The view itself )
>
> v1.superview ------- >>>  parent